# It Turns Out, I Fit in Many Places

Tags: riddle

Call me a square one if you will, but it’s not impossible for nerds to be cool
There are two big spaces that I fit in, and it is rare that I fit in both
I fit the best in spaced, but that wasn’t for too long
And when I was round, I did my best to fit then, too
Though it is not my shape, I do have a fondness for cones

Who am I?

*There is at least **one** clue to this person/thing in each line, but list any that you think apply.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

> [Simon Pegg](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0670408/?ref_=tt_cl_t8)

Call me a square one if you will, but it’s not impossible for nerds to be cool

> Square peg. He's a well known nerd.

There are two big spaces that I fit in, and it is rare that I fit in both

> He appears in both [Star Wars](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/) and [Star Trek](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0796366/), the only actor I can think of to do both.

I fit the best in spaced, but that wasn’t for too long

> His brilliant but short lived sitcom, [Spaced](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0187664/)

And when I was round, I did my best to fit then, too

> [Run Fatboy Run](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0425413/)

Though it is not my shape, I do have a fondness for cones

> The entire [Cornetto trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Flavours_Cornetto_trilogy)

Comment: Nice job, @alaxluthor.  You hit it perfectly across the board.  I didn't even need to throw in anything about an alien or alienating people.  Good first answer!

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is

> Breasts. (Just to prove my innocence I would say that i searched about conical objects and got [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081103174345AA9R8Yv) )

Call me a square one if you will, but it’s not impossible for nerds to be cool

> Calling a breast of square shaped is **not** cool

There are two big spaces that I fit in, and it is rare that I fit in both
I fit the best in spaced, but that wasn’t for too long
And when I was round, I did my best to fit then, too
Though it is not my shape, I do have a fondness for cones

> Talked about their shape and bras this whole time.

Comment: What's wrong with this answer. Why the down votes. The clues fit this answer as well. +1.

Comment: @AeJey i think i didn't explained enough..:P :D .

Comment: @manshu While I'm certainly a fan of this answer (*wink, wink*), and it did make me smile, it is not what I was looking for.  It was a creative stab taken and my guess is that the down votes were from people thinking you weren't taking the question seriously, or from people not taking your answer seriously.

Comment: @raisinghellyer i took this puzzle seriously. But the point is that i solve puzzle to learn something new. If the puzzle is about something that does not need to be known then i just skip it. I am perfectly aware of the fact that puzzle are to make u think in different way but if i can't relate myself to the puzzle than there is no meaning to solve it or maybe i should say i cant solve it.

Comment: The justifications for each line are either weak or don't make sense. Just because a search for conical objects has a hit or three with this answer in it, that doesn't make it a good answer. The explanation about cool/not cool makes no sense at all in the context of the riddle's first line. Then reducing the last four lines of the riddle to one concept seems to show a lack of understanding of how riddles are typically formed.

Comment: @ToddWilcox i accept the fact about the first line. And i didn't explained the last four lines because it would have increased the vulgarity of the answer. So i left it on the clever reader to understand it by himself.

Comment: You are totally on to something. But I think it's more about bras then breasts. They used to keep them 'spaced' - now we like cleavage. Rarely are breasts conical, but they still fit into 50's era bras somehow. It was either prior to that, or after that, that they were 'square', like a doctor's mask. I myself, have a fondness for conical (50's style) bras. And when I'm 'round (around), I try my best to *also* fit (my hands in there). Vulgarity be dammed, finish the story.

Comment: @Mazura now i know where i went wrong...:p